# ¿Cómo descargo un .txt desde HTML?

Tags: html, java-ee, servlets, file, enlace

He creado una App en Java 2EE, con Eclipse, lo que hago es buscar una cadena en un conjunto de ficheros (array ficheros) cuando los encuentra, escribe la coincidencia en un fichero .txt creado previamente.

Mi problema es que al pasar la ruta y el texto a buscar por formulario a traves de un servlet, en la siguiente página, pongo una imagen con un  a ese fichero para descargarlo, me lo descarga pero, o me dice que el formato no es el correcto, o Error de Red. ¿Qué puede pasar?

Aquí os dejo el codigo del link.

`<a href="C:/formacion/workspace_formacion/Prueba/WebContent/resultados.txt" download>`

Si voy a la ruta del Fichero y lo abro, sacar lo que quiero perfectamente. Este es el "Error" que me da.

[image: Error que me da, al darle al Link para descargar el Fichero]

Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Estás buscando un fichero en tu propio PC, no en el servidor. Como no es una URL válida, te da un error.

Comment: ¿Qué has probado? Y no me refiero al `<a>`, sino al código que en el servidor recibe la petición y procesa el resultado. Aparte, es muy diferente si el fichero obtenido es estático (basta ponerlo en la webapp) o dinámico (hay que proporcionarlo a través de un Servlet o similar).

Comment: Cómo que hay que ponerlo en Webapp? Soy nuevo con los servlets, con Tomcat etc y no se exactamente cual es el procedimiento. Yo estoy almacenando el archivo con los resultados que genero en la clase en WebContent, junto al Index.html con formulario que llama al servlet en el que llamo a esa clase.